Ag Charts Candlestick series - candle center does not correspond to time point on xAxis
I'm using ag-charts-enterprise trial and trying to display candlesticks as well as High and Low price lines on the same chart. The problem I have is that candles are not centered around the time point, for which they are rendered. This makes candlestick series "shift" to the right.

Ideally, I want candles wicks for high and low price to touch nodes of the High and Low price lines correspondingly.
Here's chart configuration I use:
// Chart Options Configuration
            const options = {
                container: document.getElementById("agChart"),
                dataSource: {
                    getData: this.fetchData.bind(this),
                },
                // Series: Defines which chart type and data to use
                series: [
                    {
                        type: "candlestick",
                        xKey: "date",
                        lowKey: "low",
                        highKey: "high",
                        openKey: "open",
                        closeKey: "close",
                     
                    },
                    {
                        type: "line",
                        xKey: "date",
                        yKey: "high",
                      
                    },
                    {
                        type: "line",
                        xKey: "date",
                        yKey: "low",
                    }
                ],
                // Axes: Configure the axes for the chart
                axes: [
                    // Display category (xKey) as the bottom axis
                    {
                        type: "time",
                        position: "bottom",
                        nice: false,
                        gridLine: {
                            enabled: true,
                        },
                        max: new Date(),
                        min: new Date(2024, 11, 1),
                        keys: ["date"],
                        interval: { step: time.hour.every(6) },
                    },
                    // Use right axis for price series
                    {
                        type: "number",
                        position: "right",
                        gridLine: {
                            enabled: true,
                        },
                        keys: ["low", "high", "open", "close"],
                    }
                ],
                // Legend: Matches visual elements to their corresponding series or data categories.
                legend: {
                    position: "right",
                },
                zoom: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                initialState: {
                    zoom: {
                        rangeX: {
                            start: {
                                __type: 'date',
                                value: new Date('2024-12-20').getTime(),
                            },
                            end: {
                                __type: 'date',
                                value: new Date('2024-12-25').getTime(),
                            },
                        },
                    }
                }
            };

One note is that if I remove xAxis configuration altogether and just use defaults, everything is rendered correctly, but that doesn't work for me, I need custom xAxis config.
